# Comparando similaridade em dois arrays!

Tags: php, porcentagem

Boa noite galera, estou com um problema, vamos lá, talvez alguém possa ajudar-me.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach ($paper as $p)
{
    $array1[] = $p->title;
    $array2[] = $p->title;
}

$nbarray1 = count($array1);
$stringSimilarity = 0;

foreach ($array1 as $word1)
{
    $max = null;
    $similarity = null;
    foreach ($array2 as $word2)
    {
        similar_text($word1, $word2, $similarity);
        if ($similarity > $max)
        {
            $max = $similarity;
        }
    }
    $stringSimilarity += $max;
    $resultado = $stringSimilarity / $nbarray1;

    if ($resultado > 90)
    {
        echo '<b>Título 1:</b> ' . $word1 . ' <br><b>Título 2:</b> ' . $word2 . ' <b><br>Resultado: POSSIVELMENTE DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = ' . number_format((float)$resultado, 0, '.', '') . '%<br></b>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<b>Título 1:</b> ' . $word1 . ' <br><b>Título 2:</b> ' . $word2 . ' <b><br>Resultado: NÃO DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = ' . number_format((float)$resultado, 0, '.', '') . '%<br></b>';
    }

}
```

**Este código tem o seguinte OUTPUT**

```
Título 1: A new method for SSD black-box performance test 
Título 2: Novel Solution for the Built-in Gate Oxide Stress Test of LDMOS in Integrated Circuits for Automotive Applications 
Resultado: NÃO DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = 25%
Título 1: Structural Health Monitoring of a rotor blade during statical load test 
Título 2: Novel Solution for the Built-in Gate Oxide Stress Test of LDMOS in Integrated Circuits for Automotive Applications 
Resultado: NÃO DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = 50%
Título 1: Using TTCN-3 in Performance Test for Service Application 
Título 2: Novel Solution for the Built-in Gate Oxide Stress Test of LDMOS in Integrated Circuits for Automotive Applications 
Resultado: NÃO DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = 75%
Título 1: Novel Solution for the Built-in Gate Oxide Stress Test of LDMOS in Integrated Circuits for Automotive Applications 
Título 2: Novel Solution for the Built-in Gate Oxide Stress Test of LDMOS in Integrated Circuits for Automotive Applications 
Resultado: POSSIVELMENTE DUPLICADO - Porcentagem = 100%
```

1. Notem que possuo apenas 4 títulos cadastrados. Como eu faria para que o título não tentasse testar a similaridade dele com ele mesmo???
2. Notem que apenas um título testou com todos os outros, o certo deveria recomeçar o loop com outro título testando novamente, e assim sucessivamente até que todos sejam testados com todos.
3. $paper é um array deste tipo

   [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#97 (26) {
       ["paper_id"]=>
       string(1) "1"
       ["title"]=>
       string(47) "A new method for SSD black-box performance test"
       ["author"]=>
       string(6) "Q. Xie"
4. Seria possível após eu verificar os duplicados, atualizar o array de objetos paper? No caso ele possui ["status"]=> e eu queria atualizar esse para duplicado caso fosse encontrado nas validações anteriores.

Se alguém com muita paciência ajudar a pensar na lógica já fico feliz, estou apanhando mas estou tentando desenvolver :D

Answer (score 1):

Isso impediria que ele verificasse a duplicada, colocando um `if()` dentro do segundo `foreach()`:

```
foreach($array2 as $word2){
//verifica se word1 é diferente de word2, se for igual ele não compara
    if($word1 != $word2){ 
        similar_text($word1, $word2, $similarity);
        if($similarity > $max){ //1)
            $max = $similarity;
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode definir esse início de outras forma que sejam menos repetitivas, por exemplo:

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach ($paper as $p) {
   $array1[] = $p->title;
   $array2[] = $p->title;
}
```

Ou apenas assim:

```
foreach ($paper as $p) {
   $array1[] = $p->title;
   $array2[] = $p->title;
}
```

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta para que fique mais claro amigo Wees

Comment: @GutoG você quer alterar o array matriz caso essa função acuse o nome duplicado??

Comment: Sim, além de também fazer aquelas mudanças que citei, como testar todos com todos e evitar que o título teste com ele mesmo

Comment: só que, você esta testando dois arrays iguais, certamente q vai ter titulos iguais,e por fim, vc vai apagar todos eles do array matriz